# Can I connect to two different websockets servers simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, websocket

I need to connect to two websockets servers simultaneously using python, as I need to amalgamate the data received from each into one file and then process it. I have  used something *like* the following successfully for one websockets feed, but can't get it to work for two feeds simultaneously:

```
from websocket import create_connection

ws_a = create_connection("wss://www.server1.com")
ws_a.send("<subscription message, server 1>")

ws_b = create_connection("wss://www.server2.com")
ws_b.send("<subscription message, server 2>")

while bln_running:
    response_a =  ws_a.recv()

    if "success" in response_a:
        ...do something...

    response_b =  ws_b.recv()
    if "success" in response_b:
        ...do something...
```

However, in this example, I receive events from only server 1. I don't think splitting it into two threads will work, as I then have two different sets of data, and I need them amalgamated. (Although challenging this statement is a possible alternative solution???)

Any guidance or advice on getting both feeds simultaneously appreciated.

Many thanks.

My python version: 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Sep 19 2017, 08:03:39) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: You could very well use threads even if you want to combine your input streams. You have to ensure their order somehow, but that you need anyway. Otherwise you could use `asyncio` or, I guess, `select.select`.

Comment: Thanks Johan. If the threads ended, I would have done that, but I don't know how to pass the data received out of the thread while it's still running. In C# I would (perhaps inelegantly) create a global variable(s) and pass the values to that. Would I do the same in Python? And if so, how?

Comment: Look at the `queue` module. (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html). It is a good way to pass messages between threads.

Answer (score 4):

This worked:

```
from websocket import create_connection
from threading import Lock, Thread

lock = Lock()
message_list = [] #global list

def collect_server1_data():
    global message_list
    bln_running = True
    ws_a = create_connection("wss://www.server1.com")
    ws_a.send("<subscription>")
    while bln_running:   
        response_a =  ws_a.recv()
        lock.acquire()
        message_list.append(response_a)
        lock.release()
        response_a = ""

def collect_server2_data(): 
    global message_list
    bln_running = True
    ws_b = create_connection("wss://www.server2.com")
    ws_b.send("<subscription>")
    while bln_running:   
        response_b =  ws_b.recv()
        lock.acquire()
        message_list.append(response_b)
        lock.release()
        response_b = ""


### --------Main--------
threads = []
for func in [collect_server1_data, collect_server2_data]:
    threads.append(Thread(target=func))
    threads[-1].start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Thanks to JohanL for the steer in the right direction.